# Putting a word between "every" and "day"

Tags: sentence-usage, adverbials

Can I put any word between **every** and **day** in these circumstances:

> I feel disappointed **every exam day.**
>
> He brings his umbrella along **every cloudy day.**

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can.

> Every **exam** day
>   *every day there is an exam*
>
> Every **cloudy** day
>   *every overcast day*
>
> Every **rainy** day
>   *every day when it rains*
>
> Every **other** day
>   *every second day*

These all act to describe the frequency of the days you want to mention.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It acts as a restriction on the phrase "every day", meaning only those days to which that adjective or attributive noun applies.

Except if it's an expletive. Then it's just for emphasis. E.g. "every **damn** day"